# Iterating through graphml file to extracting the nodes values

Tags: xml, graphml

I have thousands of grapgml files with each having data stored in the nodes. I want to iterate through each file and extract data from nodes and then store it as a CSV or JSON. Below is a small segment of the code. I want to extract values corresponding to d2, d3, d4. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key attr.name="key" attr.type="long" for="edge" id="d8" />
  <key attr.name="length_word" attr.type="long" for="node" id="d6" />
  <key attr.name="chunk_no" attr.type="long" for="node" id="d1" />
  <key attr.name="position" attr.type="long" for="node" id="d3" />
  <key attr.name="morph" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d5" />
  <key attr.name="pre_verb" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d7" />
  <key attr.name="lemma" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d4" />
  <key attr.name="cng" attr.type="long" for="node" id="d0" />
  <key attr.name="word" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d2" />
  <graph edgedefault="directed">
    <node id="1">
      <data key="d2">maDu</data>
      <data key="d0">3</data>
      <data key="d4">maDu</data>
      <data key="d7" />
      <data key="d5">iic.</data>
      <data key="d3">0</data>
      <data key="d1">1</data>
      <data key="d6">5</data>
    </node>
    <node id="2">
      <data key="d2">maDu</data>
      <data key="d0">71</data>
      <data key="d4">maDu</data>
      <data key="d7" />
      <data key="d5">acc. sg. n.</data>
      <data key="d3">0</data>
      <data key="d1">1</data>
      <data key="d6">5</data>
    </node>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0 you can transform one file using:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xpath-default-namespace="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">
  <xsl:output method="json"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="array{//node ! 
          map{'d2':string(data[@key='d2']),
              'd3':string(data[@key='d3']),
              'd4':string(data[@key='d4'])}})"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

To handle multiple files, add for example (if the files are reachable as `data/dir/*.xml`)

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('data/dir?select=*.xml')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The syntax of the collection URI here is Saxon-specific.

Not tested.

Comment: Hey Micheal, can you suggest a way to do this in python. How can I use XSLT 3.0? If any other solution is possible please let me know.

Comment: The Saxon/C product implements XSLT 3.0 and has a Python binding.